# How to define sprite priority over other?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

By default a new sprite overloads the previous on if they colide (newest is displayed over the older one)

how can I change that programatically?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sprite drawing order depends on the `zOrder`. Higher `zOrder` sprites are drawn on top of lower `zOrder` sprites. You can change the `zOrder` with:

```
- (void)reorderChild:(CCNode *)child z:(NSInteger)zOrder
```